# WCF Authentication - Username-Password using custom validator - Works on My Machine

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service and a client, that uses a custom `UserNamePasswordValidator` for authentication.

I use a self-signed certificate, created by the following command line:

```
makecert -sr LocalMachine -ss My -a sha1 -n CN=SelfSignedCertificate -sky exchange -pe
```

Calling methods in the service from the below client works fine on my machine :) But as soon as I deploy it to my server, I get this error message: `The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.`

I can browse the endpoint URL and see the WSDL for the service. I'm not sure, but I recall that I configured some Anonymous Authentication in IIS on my local machine, but it looks similar on the server as well.

My WCF service is hosted in IIS 7.0, using this configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="secured">
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="unsecured">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="secured">
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="unsecured">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="unsecured">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="Milkshake.Admin.Services.AdminService" behaviorConfiguration="CustomValidator">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Milkshake.Admin.Model.ServiceContracts.IAdminService" bindingConfiguration="secured" />
        </service>
        <service name="Milkshake.Admin.Services.DeploymentService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Milkshake.Admin.Model.ServiceContracts.IDeploymentService"/>
        </service>
        <service name="Milkshake.Admin.Services.LogService" behaviorConfiguration="CustomValidator">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Milkshake.Core.Logging.ILogService" bindingConfiguration="secured" />
        </service>
        <service name="Milkshake.Admin.Services.MailService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Milkshake.Admin.Model.ServiceContracts.IMailService"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="CustomValidator">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <serviceCertificate findValue="SelfSignedCertificate" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
                    <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Milkshake.Admin.Services.MilkshakeCredentialValidator, Milkshake.Admin.Services" />
                    <clientCertificate>
                        <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
                    </clientCertificate>
                </serviceCredentials>
                <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>

        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="json">
                <enableWebScript />
            </behavior>

            <behavior name="xml">
                <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml" defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped" />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The client configuration looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://server-url/LogService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Milkshake.Core.Logging.ILogService">
            <identity>
                <dns value="SelfSignedCertificate" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

My custom validator is this:

```
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Selectors;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Milkshake.Admin.Services
{
    /// <summary>
    /// WCF Service validator for Milkshake.
    /// </summary>
    public class MilkshakeCredentialValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// When overridden in a derived class, validates the specified username and password.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userName">The username to validate.</param>
        /// <param name="password">The password to validate.</param>
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }

            if (userName.Equals("martin") && password.Equals("normark"))
            {
                return;
            }

            FaultCode fc = new FaultCode("ValidationFailed");
            FaultReason fr = new FaultReason("Good reason");

            throw new FaultException(fr, fc);
        }
    }
}
```

My service client, looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Security;
using Milkshake.Core.Logging;

namespace Milkshake.Admin.ServiceClients.Logging
{
    /// <summary>
    /// WCF Service Client implementation of the <see cref="ILogService"/> contract.
    /// </summary>
    public class LogServiceClient : ILogService
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="LogServiceClient"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public LogServiceClient()
        {
            var factory = new ChannelFactory<ILogService>(String.Empty);
            factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
            factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "martin";
            factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "normark";

            var binding = factory.Endpoint.Binding as WSHttpBinding;

            if (binding != null)
            {
                binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
                binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
            }

            this.AdminLogService = factory.CreateChannel();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the admin log service.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The admin log service.</value>
        private ILogService AdminLogService { get; set; }

        #region ILogService Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Logs the error simple.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="applicationInstanceId">The application instance id.</param>
        /// <param name="logDate">The log date.</param>
        /// <param name="exceptionMessage">The exception message.</param>
        /// <param name="description">The description.</param>
        /// <param name="severity">The severity.</param>
        /// <param name="userAgent">The user agent.</param>
        /// <param name="source">The source.</param>
        public void LogErrorSimple(int applicationInstanceId, DateTime logDate, string exceptionMessage, string description, Severity severity, string userAgent, string source)
        {
            this.AdminLogService.LogErrorSimple(applicationInstanceId, logDate, exceptionMessage, description, severity, userAgent, source);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Logs the error advanced.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="applicationInstanceId">The application instance id.</param>
        /// <param name="logDate">The log date.</param>
        /// <param name="exceptionType">Type of the exception.</param>
        /// <param name="exceptionCode">The exception code.</param>
        /// <param name="exceptionMessage">The exception message.</param>
        /// <param name="stackTrace">The stack trace.</param>
        /// <param name="caller">The caller.</param>
        /// <param name="location">The location.</param>
        /// <param name="source">The source (A service, app etc).</param>
        /// <param name="description">The description.</param>
        /// <param name="severity">The severity.</param>
        /// <param name="username">The username.</param>
        /// <param name="userAgent">The user agent.</param>
        public void LogErrorAdvanced(int applicationInstanceId, DateTime logDate, string exceptionType, string exceptionCode, string exceptionMessage, string stackTrace, string caller, string location, string source, string description, Severity severity, string username, string userAgent)
        {
            this.AdminLogService.LogErrorAdvanced(applicationInstanceId, logDate, exceptionType, exceptionCode, exceptionMessage, stackTrace, caller, location, source, description, severity, userAgent, userAgent);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Logs the behavior with data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="applicationInstanceId">The application instance id.</param>
        /// <param name="action">The action.</param>
        /// <param name="logDate">The log date.</param>
        /// <param name="userAgent">The user agent.</param>
        /// <param name="behaviorData">The behavior data.</param>
        /// <param name="source">The source.</param>
        public void LogBehaviorWithData(int applicationInstanceId, string action, DateTime logDate, string userAgent, string behaviorData, string source)
        {
            this.AdminLogService.LogBehaviorWithData(applicationInstanceId, action, logDate, userAgent, behaviorData, source);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Logs the behavior.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="applicationInstanceId">The application instance id.</param>
        /// <param name="action">The action.</param>
        /// <param name="logDate">The log date.</param>
        /// <param name="userAgent">The user agent.</param>
        /// <param name="source">The source.</param>
        public void LogBehavior(int applicationInstanceId, string action, DateTime logDate, string userAgent, string source)
        {
            this.AdminLogService.LogBehavior(applicationInstanceId, action, logDate, userAgent, source);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: is the self signed certificate known on the server?

Comment: Yes, it is located in the Personal store on the local machine. If I change the config file to an incorrect certificate name, I'll get an error specifically outlining that the certificate could not be found.

Comment: im not sure the `basicHttpBinding` supports user name credentials in Message security. is it possible to try with wsHttpBinding?

Comment: I'm not using `basicHttpBinding`, but `wsHttpBinding`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also use the UserNamePasswordValidator with certificates generated using makecert.

Instead of using IIS, use WcfSvcHost so you can be sure it starts successfully. The reason I'm suggesting this is that possibly Chain building for the certificate is failing. There is a setting you can use to disable chain building. (**Update:** I think you're doing that already with CertificateValidationMode="none")

Another thing I'm noticing is that not all your service definitions specify behaviourConfiguration. This is a little beech to find because it gets removed sometimes by VS when you update your service references.

The exception you mention, is that the message from the inner most exception?

Comment: It is from the inner most exception. I just double checked.
Regarding IIS, is there a way to disable Chain building? I'll try the WcfSvcHost right away.

Comment: Is there an easy way to use WcfServiceHost on the server? VS2010 is not installed there...

Comment: Thought for a moment the problem is your client configuration, but I see now that you do that through code. Is there a reason why you aren't using the config file for that?

Comment: Regarding behaviourConfiguration - I don't use the add/update service references. All hosts and clients are written using the approach in this article: http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0809101

Comment: Ahhh :) Maybe there was a bunch of dependencies :)

Comment: I'm making small progress. Everything works when I use the WcfServiceHost - but it still doesn't work in IIS. Locally, I have IIS 7.5 installed, but on the server it is IIS 7.0. Maybe there are some features enabled locally, that I need to install on the server?

Comment: I should say, that the WcfSvcHost found a few errors, before it worked. Endpoints address missing, and base address not set, making the httpGetUrl fail.

Comment: That could mean it has something to do with access to the certificate from IIS. IIS runs under a different account and I recall that there is some command that you can execute from cmd to give access to certain users... I'll see if I can find that.

Comment: Another thing that could be helpful is to enable tracing and see if that spits out more detailed error messages.

Comment: The certificate access - is that WinHttpCertCfg? I just wrote a Windows Service host, and initially that didn't work either. Same error. But WcfSvcHost worked, even when I used the exact same config file. So then it hit me, that the service account was Network Service - just as I used with IIS. I changed it to LocalSystem - and now it works. I guess I need to troubleshoot further. I don't think it's to do with certificate access, since I already changed permission for the private keys on the certificate.

Comment: Did you try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702621.aspx (cacls.exe)

Comment: @Andre: I think that solved it. The cacls command only sets permission on the certificate private key, just as when you use MMC -> Cert. Mgr. for local machine -> Manage Private Key on a certificate. Then you can see permissions, but maybe cacls also does something "hidden".

Comment: This was more of a support effort than pure Q&A, but I'm glad you got it sorted :)